# Pertaining to asp.net: Value of 'checked' attribute of checkbox

Tags: asp.net, xml

I'm using an xml doc to maintain state between 3 aspx pages.  I have a problem with Checked attribute of checkboxes
:
If it's unchecked then myCheckbox.Checked = false
If it's checked then myCheckbox.Checked = True  (with initial capital)

Ideally I'd like 'True' to be lowercase, this causes a problem with the xml later down the line.
Thanks!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here, just a statement. How about you show how you are translating state to and from XML? There's likely a way of performing that translation so that you can capitalize your Boolean values however you want.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I just wondered why the checkboxes were behaving that way.  I can convert 'True' to 'true'  before writing to the xml but it took me a while to figure out why that was happening.  Also I may have many more checkboxes in other pages and don't want to have to intercept them all before writing the values. Thanks again.

Comment: @JerryMiller Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There's no sample data, minimum code to reproduce the problem or a clear question on this post.